# Flutter Web view not loading in windows desktop application

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my code snippet how to resolve this issue

Comment: Microsoft windows and Linux desktop support is still in tech preview. Only MacOS apps are out of tech preview. Might be plugins are not ready. It would be good if you can add error logs here.

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for the official support from Flutter team, you can use [`flutter-webview-windows`](https://github.com/jnschulze/flutter-webview-windows) package. It adds support for Windows webview on Flutter and can communicate between the webview and flutter app (more detail [here](https://codingwithtashi.medium.com/how-to-use-flutter-webview-windows-in-your-flutter-application-and-communicate-between-them-60050f0bb48f)).

```
final _controller = WebviewController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _init();
}

void _init() async {
  await _controller.initialize();
  await _controller.loadUrl('https://flutter.dev');

  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {});
}

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Webview')),
    body: _controller.value.isInitialized
        ? Webview(_controller)
        : const Text('Not Initialized'),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this still true in 2023 or can u use web view in 2023?

Answer (score 1):

The webview_flutter plugin [doesn't exist for Windows yet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37597), and in fact isn't possible to write yet since `PlatformView` support isn't implemented for Windows. (As [the documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#plugins) says: "there are currently few plugins that actually have desktop support".)

Currently if you want a web view in your application it would need to be in a separate window, and you would need to write a plugin that creates and managers that Windows and web view.